# Visual Force is not Rendering Inline Css when rendered as PDF

Tags: visualforce, pdf, renderas

In Our Application , We are getting a formatted Html string from a external library(Bryntnum - provides gantt chart features).

The Formatted Html is returned in a string format.

Our business need is to convert this html into vf page and render it as a pdf.
When I just use the html string and use it in vf page all the css is loaded correctly.

Image ( apex page which is not rendered as pdf)
[image: apex page which is not rendered as pdf]

Output
[image: Output when not renderred as pdf]

Now if i try to render the same vf page as pdf it does not load any css.
[image: Adding renderaspdf to vf page.]

Output:
[image]

This is the original html string which is coming from a third party library.
It would be really helpful if someone can help me on how i can get pdf to have css.

Steps to get the result.
Open Developer Console in Salesforce.
Create a dummy vf page.
and Copy the below Html text which is inside the text file
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BV98W5ZQ84khhsNuRgCyItsnvKKSKcoRVjFe2GMbsE4/edit

Comment: In my experience, it completely ignores inline CSS and you are forced to actually use "style" attributes for the individual elements in the page. Total PITA.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, you need to apply a few attributes to the `apex:page`, including `applyHtmlTag` and `applyBodyTag`. Here's an example that works:

## Static Resource q361913

```
div {
    color : red;
}
```

## Page

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" showChat="false" showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false">
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{!URLFOR($Resource.q361913)}" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
                Hello World
            </div>
            
        </body>    
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

---

## Output

[image: Sample PDF]

Note that only CSS1 and CSS2 is supported, so any more advanced CSS may not render the way you expect.